# How can I get specific column fields?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want return specific columns for every card that is returned by eloquent relationship.
I can do it with ->get(['column1', 'column2']) but in this situation I can't use get().
Is there a solution for this ?

```
$deckId = $request->deckId;
$deck = Deck::find($deckId);
return $deck->cards;
```

on the cards I want for example just the id the name and the card_type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work if you already defined the relationship

```
return $deck->cards()->get(['id', 'name', 'card_type']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-pluck)?

```
Deck::all()->pluck('column1', 'column2');
```

This will return an array with column1 as key and column2 as value